# Help joining two polygon layers using ArcGIS Spatial Join

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, spatial-join, feature-layer

I am trying to use ArcGIS Pro to spatially join approximately 600,000 polygons in [ESRI TitleInfo](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis-marketplace/listing/products/10f8627d0f2f4714b04b7ae292cec366) with the polygons in [this London landuse dataset](https://maps.london.gov.uk/gla/rest/services/IMA/IMA_context_information_landuse/MapServer/1). However, the spatial join fails to match any record. When I use TitleInfo as the target, the spatial join appends the landuse columns but all of the entries are null (the opposite occurs when I use landuse as the target). The problem persists across merge methods (intersection, closest, etc) and even when I extend the search radius to 1000m. I checked the coordinates for both datasets and they seem to be identical as far as I can tell (see below).

I have gone over the existing discussions in GIS SE but was unable to find any solution. I am really not sure what the problem is here. I am new to GIS so I might be overlooking a basic issue.

How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also tried joining the two datasets using the ArcGIS online map viewer with no success. This suggests to me that the issue might be with the datasets. Can someone please let me know if the datasets are somehow incompatible or if there is an alternative way to spatially join the two data?

Comment: How are you accessing the Title Info data, following your link its a premium paid for dataset, may be they have disabled spatial joining if the data is accessed directly via a server? Can you download the data locally to your c:\ drive and do the join?

Comment: I have it downloaded as an ArcGIS Pro Portal Item, but I am not sure if the server is queried when I open this item. It is definitely possible that spatial joining has been disabled. Is there a way to check if this is true? I'm finding that part of my issue with getting around ArcGIS is that the error messages are vague and don't quite point you to the true source of the issue.

Comment: Right click on the layer in your map and look at its properties, source tab to confirm source of data, then try to export it locally?

Comment: @Hornbydd I downloaded the proprietary TitleInfo data but I still can't get the datasets to join. I am having trouble downloading the landuse dataset locally. The export options are greyed out. I believe ArcGIS queries an API on the server for the landuse data. Do you think the issue is because of the publicly available landuse dataset that cannot be downloaded? Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Looks like that London land use map is a vector tile layer. I don't believe the underlying data is exposed to querying/export it's meant to be a static base map as discussed [here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/tile-layers.htm).  You will not be able to join such data. I suggest you contact the [Author](https://www.arcgis.com/home/user.html?user=GLAGIS) to see if they will give you access to the underlying data.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for pointing that out. I will look into it.